# After how much time does Spider-Man's web decompose?

Tags: spider-man, marvel, the-amazing-spider-man

Spider-Man can spin web from his wrist, and once he does so, uses it to swing. then he releases it and it is hanging all around the city buildings. So my question is: after how much time does Spider-Man's web decompose?

Comment: @phantom42: While I agree that the 2nd part of that question and the accepted answer do answer this question, I don't believe 'Duplicate' is the right thing to say here.  I wouldn't believe, reading that question's title, that it would answer this question.  This question, if it gets answers as good as the other, will make the Internet a better place.  Isn't that the standard we're trying to meet?

Comment: @jeff, you're correct - the titles don't indicate that they're dupes. When I was searching through the old questions, it didn't stand out as the one I was looking for even though I knew it had been discussed. If the questions are merged, the question remains searchable, but the users are directed (not automatically) to the existing question/answer. Perhaps the title of the other question should be edited to better reflect  the body of the question, which *does* ask about the time before the webbing dissolves.

Comment: @jeff Would hope that folks using the site do a bit more diligence than just reading the question titles.  Doing a search for 'spider-man web decompose' gets the 'duplicate' being referred to. And as phantom42 says, the users get a link from this question to the 'duplicate' when they're merged.

Answer (score 5):

In the comics it has typically been said that his webbing breaks down within about an hour.

This was also referenced in the 1990's Fox animated series, in the episode which introduced Mysterio.

One big clue that the false Spider-man was not real was that his webbing didn't break down - a strand of it lasted overnight.  The cops, of course, didn't take this as valid evidence and postulated that Spidey had changed his formula.